# Deploy Recurrent Neural Network to flask web service

Tags: python, machine-learning, flask, deep-learning, recurrent-neural-network

I have simple Recurrent Neural Network (RNN) model. And I want to deploy it to flask web service. How can I deploy it to flask web service ?

Answer (score 2):

Since you did not provide any information about you model here, I am going to give you an MVP to put RNN as a service in Flask.

```
import keras
from keras.models import load_model
from flask import Flask, render_template, jsonify
from flask import request

model = load_model('recurrent_neural_network.h5', compile=False)
model.compile(loss='YOUR_DESIRED_LOSS_FUNCTION',
          optimizer='YOUR_DESIRED_OPTIMIZER',
          metrics=[YOUR_DESIRED_MATRICS])

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config["DEBUG"] = True


@app.route('/', methods=['GET'])
def home():
    return "<h1>RNN MODEL</h1>"


@app.route('/PREDICTION_ROUTE',methods=['POST'])
def PREDICTION_ROUTE():
    req = request.get_json()
    document = req["document"]
    preprocessed_document = YOUR_PREPROCESSOR_FUNCTION(document)
    prediction = model.predict(preprocessed_document)
    return jsonify({
            "prediction": prediction
        })

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```